# Lync UIsupressed Client: No Photo of contacts

Tags: lync-client-sdk

I've asked this question on the MSDN forums a week ago, but unfortunately I don't get a reply. This functionality is so basic that I can't imagine this can't be done.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6aaaefe-92e1-45b3-8b41-8edbc9866058/cannot-get-picture-of-contacts?forum=communicatorsdk

We are developing a Lync SupressedUI Client with the Lync Client SDK.
We want to show the photo of contacts of the logged in user.
When we turn off UISupression we do get a photo.
When we turn on UISupression we do not get a photo.

There are 3 ContactInformationTypes that could be relevant:
- ContactInformationType.Photo
- ContactInformationType.IconStream
- ContactInformationType.IconUrl

When using Photo it does work when UISupression is turned off. 
But not when UISupression is turned on.
The exception that we get is: ItemNotFoundException

When using IconStream we get the exception: FileNotFound Exception. 
The exception does not tell which file. This is part of the message: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002

When calling ContactInformationType.IconUri we are getting an ItemNotFoundException.

Showing the photo of the logged in user is not a problem at all.
Strange enough when contacts are in the frequently used contacts group we do get a photo.

Has anybody made it work to show photos of contactpersons when UISupression is turned on?

Answer (score 0):

By accident we have a solution that does show the photos of the contacts.

it's needed to start a conversation for every contact in the contactlist.
after that the Photo can be obtained.